# Setup MySQL back-end for Azure Offline Sync

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am implementing Offline sync functionality using Azure Mobile SDK by following below mentioned link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk

For database, I am using **Azure MySQL** service and configured the connection string in App Service. While getting TodoTable collection I am getting some exception.
The store type 'rowversion' could not be found in the MySql provider manifest

Is there a way to configure and run Azure Mobile Services to work with My SQL or not?
NuGet Packages used for MySql:

- MySql.Data
- MySql.Data.EntityFramework

Please find complete stack trace if required.

> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The store type
>   'rowversion' could not be found in the MySql provider
>   manifest","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, String name)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty
>   column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.BinaryPropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty
>   column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty
>   column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean
>   allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(Tuple2
>   pm)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable 1
>   ts, Action 1 action)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable1
>   propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean
>   allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1
>   propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean
>   allowOverride)\r\n at
>    System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType
>   entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, ICollection1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy2.GetValue(TInput input)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.get_InternalContext()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.HandleNullPropagationOptionHelper.GetDefaultHandleNullPropagationOption(IQueryable
>   query)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.OrderByQueryOption.ApplyToCore(IQueryable
>   query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable
>   query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ApplyQuery(IQueryable
>   queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object
>   response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

Comment: Are you using Azure Database for MySQL or are you using a ClearDB (Azure in-app DB) instance? First, make sure all your configuration is correct: Making project configuration changes to the Web.config file for your application - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider#making-project-configuration-changes-to-the-webconfig-file-for-your-application

Comment: Additionally, the tutorial you are referencing is based upon Azure SQL Database. Let me see if there is a better doc...